# apex:outputLink (in VisualForce Page) to Custom Lightning Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-experience

Generally, in our custom visualforce pages we have a link from the record edit for that gets the user back to the listing page for the given custom sObject that looks something like:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.MyObject__c.List,$ObjectType.MyObject__c)}">Back to: MyObject List</apex:outputLink>
```

For ope specific custom object we have created a custom listing page in Lightning App Builder.  How are we supposed to generate the apex:outputLink to direct the user to this custom listing page?

Answer (score 0):

Just provide the page name as `"/lightning/n/YourCustomLightningPageName"` in value attribute of `apex:outputLink` and it will redirect to your lightning app page

If you have namespace the url will be 
`lightning/n/namespace__YourCustomLightningPageName`

Comment: What about namespace?  If this Lightning page is deployed via managed package wouldn't the name of the page need to contain the namespace as well?  Wondering if there is some function that does the right thing (to get the name with the namespace if appropriate).

Comment: @Homerlex if you have namespace the url will be  lightning/n/namespace__YourCustomLightningPageName

Comment: yes, I understand what the url will be with and without the namespace.  I was hoping there was a function that would generate the url based on whether or not it has a namespace.